# How to unset 1 result in a query object in cakephp 3

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0, cakephp-3.4

I want to get data from a table, loop through it and "unset" some entities before passing it to the view.

```
$shops = $table-find();
foreach ($shops as $shop) {
    if (condition 1) {
        unset($shop); //
    }
}
```

In the end I want to have a clean query with reduced results.

I tried to loop through $shops with `formatResults()` and `map()` but I was only able to set the entities to null.

Comment: Could you just add the condition to the find?  Something like `$shops = $table->find()->where(!condition 1)`

Comment: If you really want to do it manually instead of addition condition on your query, you can use the `toArray()` function, so you'll have an array and be able to unset the entities you want. So something like `$shops = $table->find()->toArray();`